# R preprocessing (adding ;)

Tags: r, preprocessor, delimiter

I need to look at the end of each line in csv file, and to add `;` if there is not one.

The thing is, when I read file line by line (`data <- read.table(path, sep="\n")`) and save it, the output goes from:

```
"a";"b";"c"
```

to:

```
"a;b;c"
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Hi, how do you save your file ? Are you using `write.csv` or `write.csv2` ?

Comment: write.csv(data, file=path, row.names=FALSE, na="NULL", col.names=TRUE, sep=";")

Comment: that is probably caused by read.csv, where I'm using sep="\n". But dont know how to transform it in to original separation by ";"

Comment: try modifying `eol = "\n"`

Comment: in write.csv? that didn't work

Comment: hum, and did try reading your file with `read.csv` instead of `read.table` ?

Comment: 1) `read.csv` in the file normally (as a data.frame); 2) `paste` a semicolon to all values in the last column; and 3) `write.table` again with `sep = ';'`